# Структуры в файле с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, файлы, структуры

Создаю структуру. Ввожу данный . Сохраняю в файл. Затем вынимаю из файла и вывожу на экран.

```
struct sname
{
char fio[256];
int vozrast;
};sname s;
int main()
{   SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
FILE * kar;
        kar = fopen("kar.bin", "wb");
        cout << "Введите ФИО:";
        cin.getline(s.fio, 256);
        cout << "Введите возраст:";
        cin >> s.vozrast;
        cin.ignore();
        fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, kar);
        fclode(kar);

       kar= fopen("kar.bin", "rb");
       fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, kar);
       cout << "ФИО:"<<s[i].fio<<endl;
       cout << "Возраст:" << s[i].vozrast << endl;
       fclose(kar);

return 0;
}
```

Каждый раз когда я ввожу данные структуры    `char fio[256]; int vozrast;` сохраняются в файле. И как сделать цикл просмотра. Допустим я введу 5 записей с элементами`char fio[256]; int vozrast;` и в файле уже сохранен 2 записи. Того выходит 7 записей. Как сделать автоматический цикл, ну который определит, что в файле 7 записей структуры и выведет их на экран?

Answer (score 1):

все очень просто. Читаем в цикле, пока не достигнем конца файла

```
FILE * pFile;
sname sn;
int n = 0;
pFile = fopen ("kar.bin","rb");
if (pFile==NULL) perror ("Ошибка открытия файла");
else {
    while (fread(&sn, sizeof(sname), 1,pFile) != 1) {
      n++;
      // обрабатываем sn - печать и прочье
    }
    if (feof(pFile)) {
      puts ("Конец файла достигнут.");
      printf ("прочитано записей: %d\n", n);
    }
    else puts ("Конца файла не достигли.");
    fclose (pFile);
}
```

`feof` в `while` вставлять нет смысла - он делает немного не то, что от него обычно ожидают - он не проверяет, будет ли сейчас конец файла, а проверяет, не был ли конец файла, когда с него последний раз читали (а в этом случае там будет не 1 - то есть, не одна запись).

Comment: Если вывалились из while и не достигли конца файла, значит произошла какая-то ошибка. Може имеет смысл заменить в else puts на perror?

Comment: все можно. Это на совести TC. Я написал для него в си стиле, так как он так у себя написал. А это тоже можно было бы переписать.